# Subtract column over column avoiding a string contains in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, with cumulative results quarter by quarter and resets at 1°Q.

I need the Quarter net variation, so I need to subtract column over column except the ones with 1°Q.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = {'Financials': ['EPS','Earnings','Sales','Margin'],
        '1°Q19': [1,2,3,4],
        '2°Q19': [2,4,6,8], 
        '3°Q19': [3,6,9,12],
        '4°Q19': [4,8,12,16],
        '1°Q20': [1,2,3,4],
        '2°Q20': [2,4,6,8],
        '3°Q20': [3,6,9,12],
        '4°Q20': [4,8,12,16]
        }

df = DataFrame(data,columns=['Financials','1°Q19','2°Q19','3°Q19','4°Q19',
                             '1°Q20','2°Q20','3°Q20','4°Q20'])
print(df)

  Financials  1°Q19  2°Q19  3°Q19  4°Q19  1°Q20  2°Q20  3°Q20  4°Q20
0        EPS      1      2      3      4      1      2      3      4
1   Earnings      2      4      6      8      2      4      6      8
2      Sales      3      6      9     12      3      6      9     12
3     Margin      4      8     12     16      4      8     12     16
```

I've started like this and then I got stuck big time:

```
if ~df.columns.str.contains('1°Q'):
#    here I want to substract (1°Q remains unchanged), 2°Q - 1°Q, 3°Q - 2°Q, 4°Q - 3°Q
```

In order to get this desired result:

```
  Financials  1°Q19  2°Q19  3°Q19  4°Q19  1°Q20  2°Q20  3°Q20  4°Q20
0        EPS  1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1   Earnings  2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0
2      Sales  3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0
3     Margin  4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0
```

I've tried

```
new_df = df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df)
print(new_df)
```

But the result in this case is not the desired one for de 1°Q20:

```
  Financials  1°Q19  2°Q19  3°Q19  4°Q19  1°Q20  2°Q20  3°Q20  4°Q20
0        EPS    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0   -3.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1   Earnings    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0   -6.0    2.0    2.0    2.0
2      Sales    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0   -9.0    3.0    3.0    3.0
3     Margin    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0  -12.0    4.0    4.0    4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with **`axis=1`** and then fill `NaN` with
[`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
new_df = df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Financials  1°Q  2°Q  3°Q  4°Q
0        EPS  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   Earnings  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
2      Sales  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
3     Margin  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

for expected output:

```
new_df = new_df.astype(int)
```

**EDIT**

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.contains('1°Q').cumsum(),axis=1).diff(axis=1).fillna(df)

  Financials  1°Q19  2°Q19  3°Q19  4°Q19  1°Q20  2°Q20  3°Q20  4°Q20
0        EPS    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1   Earnings    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0    2.0
2      Sales    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0    3.0
3     Margin    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0
```

or

```
df.diff(axis=1).T.mask(df.columns.to_series().str.contains('1°Q')).T.fillna(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this works just fine for one year, but when I have multiple years it doesn't work because I need to skip 1°Q. I've added an edit to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `df.shift` for the subtraction, and `fillna` to fix the `NaN` values left from the shift

```
df=df.set_index('Financials')

df-(df.shift(1, axis=1).fillna(0))

            1°Q 2°Q 3°Q 4°Q
Financials              
EPS         1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
Earnings    2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
Sales       3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0
Margin      4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: `set_index` not neccesary here

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this works just fine for one year, but when I have multiple years it doesn't work because I need to skip 1°Q. I've added an edit to my post.